# Symbols are not recognize linux driver

Tags: linux-kernel

I try to load a linux driver and I got this message :

```
# modprobe hci_uart
hci_uart: Unknown symbol hci_free_dev (err 0)
hci_uart: Unknown symbol hci_alloc_dev (err 0)
hci_uart: Unknown symbol bt_info (err 0)
hci_uart: Unknown symbol bt_err (err 0)
hci_uart: Unknown symbol hci_unregister_dev (err 0)
hci_uart: Unknown symbol hci_recv_frame (err 0)
hci_uart: Unknown symbol hci_register_dev (err 0)
hci_uart: Unknown symbol bt_warn (err 0)
hci_uart: Unknown symbol hci_free_dev (err 0)
hci_uart: Unknown symbol hci_alloc_dev (err 0)
hci_uart: Unknown symbol bt_info (err 0)
hci_uart: Unknown symbol bt_err (err 0)
hci_uart: Unknown symbol hci_unregister_dev (err 0)
hci_uart: Unknown symbol hci_recv_frame (err 0)
hci_uart: Unknown symbol hci_register_dev (err 0)
hci_uart: Unknown symbol bt_warn (err 0)
modprobe: can't load module hci_uart (kernel/drivers/bluetooth/bluetooth_uart_driver/hci_uart.ko): unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter
```

The module is checked in `linux-menuconfig` (I use `buildroot`), I tried to load an other linux driver and I do not get this message.

Any idea.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I found out, there were a trouble dependencies, so from linux-menuconfig I added the dependencies needed. I checked the makefile to know which one I had to add.

Comment: Can you elaborate who dependencies were unsatisfied and what did you add?

Comment: I am off for 10 days,  I don' t remember,  can you post your makefile,  and i Will check ?